# Assertion Error when logging.exception(error)

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have this function in a script called mymodule.py

```
import logging

def foo():
    try:
        raise ConnectionError('My Connection Error')
    except ConnectionError as ce:
        logging.exception(ce)
```

And I have the test for it called test_mymodule.py:

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock as um
import mymodule

class TestLoggingException(unittest.TestCase):

    @um.patch('mymodule.logging')
    def test_connection_error_correctly_logged_without_raising(self, mock_logging):
        mymodule.foo()

        mock_logging.assert_has_calls(
            [um.call(ConnectionError('My Connection Error'))]
        )
```

However, when running test_mymodule.py, the below assertion error is raised.

```
AssertionError: Calls not found.
Expected: [call(ConnectionError('My Connection Error'))]
Actual: [call(ConnectionError('My Connection Error'))]
```

Why is it thinking they are different and how could I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that two instances of `ConnectionError`, even if create with the same arguments, are not equal.

You create two instances in your code : in `foo` and in the `um.call()`.
However, those two instance are not the same, and are therefore not equal. You can illustrate that simply:

```py
>>> ConnectionError("test") == ConnectionError("test")
False
```

One solution is to check which calls were made to the mockup. The calls are exposed through a variable called `mockup_calls`.
Something like this

```py
class TestLoggingException(unittest.TestCase):

    @um.patch('mymodule.logging')
    def test_connection_error_correctly_logged_without_raising(self, mock_logging):
        mymodule.foo()

        print("Calls are: ", mock_logging.mock_calls)

        # Check that logging was called with logging.exception(ConnectionError("My Connection Error"))
        calls = mock_logging.mock_calls
        assert(len(calls) == 1)
        # Unpack call
        function_called, args, kwargs = calls[0]
        assert(function_called == "exception")
        connection_error = args[0]

        assert(isinstance(connection_error, ConnectionError))
        assert(connection_error.args[0] == "My Connection Error")  # This will depend on how ConnectionError is defined
```

What is tricky about this example is that it would work with types that evaluate equal even if they are not the same, like `str`(`"hi" == "hi"` will yield `True`), but not most classes.

Does it help ?